# Increase speed of IE table import

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

I have this code that pulls data from an already opened internet explorer document.  The problem is, the table is huge (30x5000) and it takes over 1 minute to move all the data into a sheet using For loops.  I would like to get this transfer of data much faster if possible.  Would it be possible to just copy/paste the entire page into the sheet?  Any other solutions?

```
 Set doc = ie.Document
 Set hTable = doc.GetElementsByTagName("table")

 For Each tb In hTable

    Set hBody = tb.GetElementsByTagName("tbody")
    For Each bb In hBody

        Set hTR = bb.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tr In hTR

             Set hTD = tr.GetElementsByTagName("td")
             y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
             For Each td In hTD
               ws.Cells(z, y).Value = td.innertext
               y = y + 1
             Next td
             DoEvents
             z = z + 1
        Next tr
        Exit For
    Next bb
Exit For
Next tb
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50115936/edit) to include more information.  Please don't be surprised if your question is moved to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - often working code in need of improvement is better handled over there.  As for this, you might be able to use XSLT to render a CSV of the table, then import that file.

Comment: Write all the data to an array, then write to the Excel Sheet once.

Comment: 1) Is there a url to share 2) If this code is working, as is, then as mentioned above, maybe more a candidate for Code Review as an optimization problem?

Answer (score 0):

Loops are inherently slow.  You can try to import the entire table using the Macro Recorder.  I'm not sure that will be any faster though.  You didn't provide a URL, so it is impossible to test this concept.  If you can't speed it up using Excel, consider doing the same using R or Python.  I have personally experienced around 10,000x improvement , and even 100,000x improvement in several processes using R or Python, instead of Excel.